# JsonReaderException - works on local, not on remote

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, dataservice

```
JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

I am trying to find a cause of this error. Any idea to where I could check would be welcome.

I am having an app where I can run with no issues on localhost. On remote server I am getting this error when data is retrieved, so I assumed maybe it is data. So I changed the data source on local, with no issues on local.

So data is out of question then, or is there something I am missing?

Comment: your are getting html/xml data instead of JSON, show how you obtain the text you are trying to parse and what this text is

Comment: if you create json result from aspx page and remote server getting an error, result can be html format. check server result an other client tool like postman..

Comment: Possibly your are not passing JSON to DeserializeObject. can you show code where you DeserializeObject? are you passing file then make sure you pass JOSN rather then file path

Answer (score 0):

As it was noticed in comments more likely your remote service is setup to return XML instead `JSON`. Please check your bindings and remote service configuration to make sure both use `JSON` for communication.

Comment: which explains working on localhost and not on remote. hm that's tricky